# How to access an S3 object from a remotely executed fargate task?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, remote-execution

I've written a java program to read from an S3 bucket, that's running in a Fargate task on AWS, but is failing with an `AccessDeniedException`
The program is in a jar file that is being executed remotely using [ECS Exec](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/new-using-amazon-ecs-exec-access-your-containers-fargate-ec2/)
The task role for the Fargate task has the following permissions, but the following lines still fail with this below exception

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectacl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        }
    ]
}

ListObjectsV2Request req = new ListObjectsV2Request().withBucketName("myBucket").withMaxKeys(200);
ListObjectsV2Result result = amazonS3.listObjectsV2(req);

com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 0Z58XY0CF91Q6H4Y; S3 Extended Request ID: sVoHHMEM4+5ti+MlcaHsgvJxyvbFlJrMVZMC4cBOFI1hPg/QtsKExqFiqNECH2ZKoUXuJMYwAt0=), S3 Extended Request ID: sVoHHMEM4+5ti+MlcaHsgvJxyvbFlJrMVZMC4cBOFI1hPg/QtsKExqFiqNECH2ZKoUXuJMYwAt0=
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1811)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1395)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1371)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4914)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4860)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4854)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjectsV2(AmazonS3Client.java:923)
    at com.mycompany.ReadS3Object.getFilesOnS3(ReadS3Object.java:263)
    at com.mycompany.ReadS3Object.run(ReadS3Object.java:141)
    at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:1939)
    at picocli.CommandLine.access$1300(CommandLine.java:145)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2352)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2346)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2311)
    at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2179)
    at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2078)
    at com.mycompany.ReadS3Object.main(ReadS3Object.java:132)
```

What needs to be changed to allow the `listObjectsV2` call to complete?

#### EDIT

So it turns out the issue was that the bucket the code was trying to list doesn't exist! When I ran the code locally, it gave the correct bucket not found exception, but running it remotely gave the AccessDeniedException. Creating the bucket resolved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your S3 V1 code is missing creds that references an IAM user that has permission to invoke S3 operations. As a test, provide that role full S3 access and see if this issue still occurs.

Also as a general recommendation, you should consider moving away from the Older V1 Amazon S3 API and consider using V2 - which is the version that Amazon recommends using when writing Java code to invoke Amazon S3 operations.

When you see the use of the **new** operator like this:

```
ListObjectsV2Request req = new ListObjectsV2Request().withBucketName("myBucket").withMaxKeys(200);
```

it's V1 code. V2 code does not use the **new** operator to create objects, but instead uses a **builder()**:

```
ListObjectsRequest listObjects = ListObjectsRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .build();
```

Comment: thanks, I've added the permissions for the role to the question

Comment: also, thanks for the advice on the V2 code, but for now I'm restricted to the V1 libraries